# What is the parameter "state_is_tuple" in TensorFlow used for?

Tags: python, parameters, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to figure out the structure of tensorflow code (r0.11) and have problems understanding the "state_is_tuple" parameter used in RNNs (currently looking at LSTMs).

In this post [How do I set TensorFlow RNN state when state_is_tuple=True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112622/how-do-i-set-tensorflow-rnn-state-when-state-is-tuple-true) it is said that the state_is_tuple option sets wether the state of the **hidden neurons** and the **cell state** are **saved in a tuple or not**.

So my questions are: Why does this parameter exist? What is it used for and **why should I bother**? In what cases should I set it to True/False?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a change to an earlier implementation of the rnn_cell-class in which state was a concatenation of the hidden neurons and the cell state. In I think Release 0.11 this was changed to a preferred version of (hidden neurons, cell state), thus as a tuple.

In the future the old concatenation way will be deprecated. Until then default is concatenation, but if you already use the tuple way then state_is_tuple needs to be set to true.