# how to convert the tensor state of a rnn nework in a tuple

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I want to be able to feed a initial state to a network via a placeholder and TensorFlow only allow array or tensor to be feed (And I don't know how to create a zer initiale state tuple) . But the     `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` function recquire a tuple of size 3.
In the answer of this post:
[How do I set TensorFlow RNN state when state_is_tuple=True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112622/how-do-i-set-tensorflow-rnn-state-when-state-is-tuple-true/39917340#comment79297687_39917340)

is exposed a method to do this conversion but the function utilised `l = tf.unpack(state_placeholder, axis=0)` doesn't exist anymore. How can i perform the conversion from a tensor of shape (num_layer,2,batch_size,hidden_layers) feed to a placeholder to a tupple acceptable by `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` as a initial_state argument?

Answer (score 0):

tf.unpack got replaced with tf.unstack. Can you use that instead?

Answer (score 0):

tf.unstack seems to do the work but the `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` still throw me an eror message : `AttributeError: 'LSTMStateTuple' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`
If It's not an LSTMStateTuple that is expected what is it?

The total stack trace error is:
[image]