# Tensorflow RNN how to create zero state with various batch size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In this question [How do I set TensorFlow RNN state when state_is_tuple=True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112622/how-do-i-set-tensorflow-rnn-state-when-state-is-tuple-true): the accepted answer initialize the initial state like this:

```
state_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [num_layers, 2, batch_size, state_size])
```

I assume this requires a specific batch size, while what I have now is:

```
inputSeq = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, seqLength, observationDim], name='input_seq')
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputSeq, initial_state=initialState)
```

And I want this `initialState` to be a zero state, and can be configurable as the batch size of `inputSeq` could vary. However, `cell.zero_state` does not accept None as batch size. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell.zero_state` accepts a scalar tensor.

Get the batch size of the place holder via `tf.shape`, then it is done:

`B = tf.shape(state_placeholder)[0]  # the batch size scalar tensor
initial_state = cell.zero_state(B)`

Comment: Thanks! I've tried get_shape() and haven't thought about this.