# resetting c_t and h_t in LSTM every couple of sequences in RNN

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to implement RNN in Tensorflow for text prediction. I am using BasicLSTMCell for this purpose, with sequence lengths of 100.

If I understand correctly, the output activation `h_t` and the activation `c_t` of the LSTM are reset each time we enter a new sequence (that is, they are updated 100 times along the sequence, but once we move to the next sequence in the batch, they are reset to 0).

Is there a way to prevent this from happening using Tensorflow? That is, to continue using the updated `c_t` and `h_t` along all the sequences in the batch? (and then to reset them when moving to the next batch).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241410/tensorflow-remember-lstm-state-for-next-batch-stateful-lstm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you would want to do that since each example in the batch should be independent.  If they are not you should just have a batch size of 1 and a sequence of length 100 * batch_size.  Often you might want to save the state in between batches.  In this case you would need to save the RNN state to a variable or as I like to do allow the user to feed it in with a placeholder.

Comment: There's a `stateful_rnn` in Keras and it has a purpose, for example dealing with varying length sequences.

Comment: Yes but that saves it between batches like I said and it does not apply the state to the next sequence in the batch.

Comment: I agree most times `stateful_rnn` isn't needed for batch setting. However there are times batches of long and wide sequences doesn't fit well into memory.