# Stateful LSTM in Tensorflow 1.0

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to implement a stateful LSTM in Tensorflow.
This is a related question [TensorFlow: Remember LSTM state for next batch (stateful LSTM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241410/tensorflow-remember-lstm-state-for-next-batch-stateful-lstm?rq=1)

When I print out the hidden state h, it does update on each iteration. However, the neural net is not learning anything (even though it was learning when I was passing the entire dataset to the neural net).

Any suggestion regarding what's going on?

```
lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(sizes[0], state_is_tuple=True)
lstm2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(sizes[1],state_is_tuple=True) 
stacked_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm, lstm2]) 

hidden_state_in = stacked_lstm.zero_state(48, tf.float32)
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm, x, initial_state=hidden_state_in)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for ep in range(0, epochs):
        t=0
        all_ll = []
        while t < len(df_x)-48:
            dx = df_x[t:t+48]
            dy = df_y[t:t+48]

            if t == 0:
                h = sess.run(hidden_state_in)
                _, out, ll, hidden_state = sess.run([train_op, p, loss, state],
                                                    feed_dict={hidden_state_in: h,
                                                               x: np.reshape(dx, (-1, timestep, feat)),
                                                               Y: np.reshape(dy, (-1, timestep))})
            else:
                _, out, ll, hidden_state = sess.run([train_op, p, loss, state],
                                                    feed_dict={hidden_state_in: hidden_state,
                                                               x: np.reshape(dx, (-1, timestep, feat)),
                                                               Y: np.reshape(dy, (-1, timestep))})
```

Comment: any solution？thx