# Tensorflow Estimator API: Remember LSTM state from previous batch for next batch with dynamic batch_size

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I know that a similar question has been already asked several times here on stackoverflow and across the Internet, but I am just not able to find a solution for the following problem: I am trying to build a stateful LSTM model in tensorflow and its **Estimator API**. 
I tried the solution of [Tensorflow, best way to save state in RNNs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969065/tensorflow-best-way-to-save-state-in-rnns?noredirect=1&lq=1), which works as long as i am using a static `batch_size`. Having a dynamic batch_size causes the following problem:

> ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified:
>   Tensor("DropoutWrapperZeroState/MultiRNNCellZeroState/DropoutWrapperZeroState/LSTMCellZeroState/zeros:0",
>   shape=(?, 200), dtype=float32)

Setting `tf.Variable(...., validate_shape=False)` just moves the problem further down the Graph:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 576, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=run_experiment)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "model.py", line 137, in run_experiment
    hparams=params  # HParams
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 210, in run
    return _execute_schedule(experiment, schedule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py", line 47, in _execute_schedule
    return task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 495, in train_and_evaluate
    self.train(delay_secs=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 275, in train
    hooks=self._train_monitors + extra_hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 660, in _call_train
    hooks=hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 241, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 560, in _train_model
    model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 545, in _call_model_fn
    features=features, labels=labels, **kwargs)
  File "model.py", line 218, in model_fn
    output, state = get_model(features, params)
  File "model.py", line 567, in get_model
    model = lstm(inputs, params)
  File "model.py", line 377, in lstm
    output, new_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multicell, inputs=inputs, initial_state = states)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 574, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 737, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2770, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2599, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2549, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 722, in _time_step
    (output, new_state) = call_cell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 708, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 752, in __call__
    output, new_state = self._cell(inputs, state, scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 441, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 916, in call
    cur_inp, new_state = cell(cur_inp, cur_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 752, in __call__
    output, new_state = self._cell(inputs, state, scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 441, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 542, in call
    lstm_matrix = _linear([inputs, m_prev], 4 * self._num_units, bias=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1002, in _linear
    raise ValueError("linear is expecting 2D arguments: %s" % shapes)
ValueError: linear is expecting 2D arguments: [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(62)]), TensorShape(None)]
```

According to [github issue 2838](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2838) it is NOT recommended to use non-trainable variables anyway(???), which is why I continued looking for other solutions.

Now I use placeholders and something like that (also suggested in the github thread) in my `model_fn`:

```py
def rnn_placeholders(state):
    """Convert RNN state tensors to placeholders with the zero state as default."""
    if isinstance(state, tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple):
        c, h = state
        c = tf.placeholder_with_default(c, c.shape, c.op.name)
        h = tf.placeholder_with_default(h, h.shape, h.op.name)
        return tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(c, h)
    elif isinstance(state, tf.Tensor):
        h = state
        h = tf.placeholder_with_default(h, h.shape, h.op.name)
        return h
    else:
        structure = [rnn_placeholders(x) for x in state]
        return tuple(structure)


state = rnn_placeholders(cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32))

for tensor in flatten(state):
    tf.add_to_collection('rnn_state_input', tensor)

x, new_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(...)

for tensor in flatten(new_state):
    tf.add_to_collection('rnn_state_output', tensor)
```

But unfortunately I do not know how to use the placeholder `new_state` to feed back its values to the placeholder `state` every iteration, **when using `tf.Estimator` API etc**.  Since I am quite new to Tensorflow I think I have a lack of conceptual knowledge here. Might it be possible to use a custom `SessionRunHook`?:

```py
class UpdateHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):

        def before_run(self, run_context):
            run_args = super(UpdateHook, self).before_run(run_context)
            run_args = tf.train.SessionRunArgs(new_state)

            #print(run_args)
            return run_args

        def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
            #run_values gives the actual value of new_state.
            # How to update now the state placeholder??
```

Is there anyone who has an idea how to solve that problem? Tips and tricks are highly appreciated!!!
Thanks a lot!

PS: If something is unclear let me know ;)

EDIT: Unfortunately I am using the new tf.data API and cannot use  `StateSavingRNNEstimator` as Eugene suggested.

Comment: Could you figure out an actual solution? I created a placeholder for the batch_size and get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this answer might be late.
I had a similar problem some months ago. 
I solved it using a customised SessionRunHook. It might not be perfect in terms of performance but you can give it a try.

```
class LSTMStateHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):

 def __init__(self, params):
    self.init_states  = None
    self.current_state = np.zeros((params.rnn_layers, 2, params.batch_size, params.state_size))

 def before_run(self, run_context):
    run_args = tf.train.SessionRunArgs([tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('LSTM/output_states:0')],{self.init_states:self.current_state,},)
    return run_args

 def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
    self.current_state = run_values[0][0] //depends on your session run arguments!!!!!!!


 def begin(self):
    self.init_states = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('LSTM/init_states:0')
```

In your code where you define your lstm graph you need something like this:

```
if self.stateful is True:
        init_states = multicell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)
        init_states = tf.identity(init_states, "init_states")

        l = tf.unstack(init_states, axis=0)
        rnn_tuple_state = tuple([tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(l[idx][0], l[idx][1]) for idx in range(self.rnn_layers)])

    else:
        rnn_tuple_state = multicell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)

# Unroll RNN
output, output_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multicell, inputs=inputs, initial_state = rnn_tuple_state)

if self.stateful is True:
  output_states = tf.identity(output_states, "output_states")
  return output
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an estimator your can base your code on that uses [batch_sequences_with_states](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/training/batch_sequences_with_states).  It is called [StateSavingRNNEstimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/state_saving_rnn_estimator.py).  Unless you are using the new `tf.contrib.data` / `tf.data` API, it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Eugene. I'll have a look at the code, but unfortunately I am using the new tf.data API. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Derek Murray has given this some thought; I am hoping something will show up in `tf.contrib.data` that allows you to push values back onto the input pipeline like a FIFO queue.  As of now, our solutions are still based on the old queue mechanisms.

Comment: Any news on this @EugeneBrevdo?